# xrdp installation script

Tags: clipboard, xrdp

Here I have found a automated script which installs xrdp and Mate Desktop environment which supports clipboard and drivers:

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9285

Security is not really my forte, could you please help me identify is it safe to use that script?

I was not able to google any information about this script at other trusted sites.

Answer (score 1):

The script is not dangerous. The script basically list step by steps the command you would manually run if you want perform a manual installation.  If you are not confident with the script, copy/paste each action defined in the script  one at the time

You can try the procedure on a virtual machine to test how the script works or to execute one by one the operations defined in the script

BTW, I have written the script so you might want to have more people confirming that this script is not dangerous.  Finally, note the disclaimer, use the script at your own risk...

Till next time 
See ya